# Insert object in Excel via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro in which the user gets an pop up in which he/she can select the file which they want to upload. (mainly images)
I've got an .OLEObjects setup, but I keep getting an error.

VBA so far:

```
Sub add_file()

Dim Fl As Variant
Dim Filename As String

ChDrive "C:"
ChDir "C:\temp"

Fl = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If Fl = False Then Exit Sub

Filename = Mid$(F1, InStrRev(F1, "\") + 1, Len(F1))

Sheet1.OLEObjects.Add Filename:=Filename, Link:=True, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=Filename

End Sub
```

Error:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Add method of OLEObjects class failed
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Fl` and `F1` are not the same

Comment: I suspect you just want `Filename:=Fl`. In recording a macro, the `Filename` parameter took the full file path. That said, you really really really need to use `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Option Explicit` and

```
Filename = Mid$(Fl, InStrRev(Fl, "\") + 1, Len(Fl))
```

You may want to read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/what-do-option-strict-and-option-explicit-do) although it covers .Net it is also applicable for VBA.